# Names of certain morphisms in Pos

Tags: terminology, category-theory, order-theory

**Pos** is the category of small posets and monotone maps.

I call a morphism $f:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}$ of **Pos** *monovalued* iff it maps every atom of $\mathfrak{A}$ either into an atom of $\mathfrak{B}$ or into the least element of $\mathfrak{B}$.

I call a morphism $f:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}$ of **Pos** *entire* iff it maps non-least elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ into non-least elements of $\mathfrak{B}$.

"Monovalued" and "entire" are my terminological inventions. Are there standard terminology for this?